# Render like Ikea manual

Tags: rendering

I am relatively new to Blender (about 1 year) ...

I got a big project for my company and my question is now is it possible to render objects to make them look like from an Ikea construction Manuel or are those illustrations?

[image: 3D render like ikea]

Comment: Hello! You should look into Freestyle rendering or the Line Art modifier

Comment: Technical drawings are better achieved with CAD applications like FreeCAD

Comment: For Blender search for "Blueprint" and you will find some examples. E.g. [Blender 2.93 - Blueprint Effect with NEW Line Art Modifier](https://youtu.be/jQqUQ5JOZjY)